# App problems please help

Tags: software-installation

I have Lubuntu and I tried to download a file called:ModelCreator_pre4(1).jar, but when I attempt to open it, instead of getting the true app, it shows the files (pictures,code,etc.) Not sure what to do. The link that I downloaded it from was:http://www.mrcrayfish.com/tools.php?id=mc

downloaded on Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You need to open it with java.  You may need to install it first.

From the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
java -jar '/path/to/ModelCreator_pre4(1).jar'
```

Comment: I have downloaded java but I still can not get it to work.

Comment: Did you open it with the command I gave you? (java -jar '/path/to/app') and if so what are the results?